# Undoing bitwise operations

Tags: java, bit-manipulation, bitwise-operators

I have a Java function written by another programmer, which uses bitwise manipulation.  I need a function that will undo the process (if possible).  Perhaps some of you are more savvy than I with these operators.  Here's what needs to be undone:

```
public void someFunc(int[] msg, int[] newMsg) {
    int i = SOME_LENGTH_CONSTANT;
    for (int j = 0; j < newMsg.length; j++) {
        // msg[i] Shift left by 8 bits bitwise or with next msg[i+1]
        // then bitwise not (~) and bitwise and with $FFF
        newMsg[j] = (~(((msg[i] & 0x0f) << 8) | (msg[i + 1]))) & 0xfff;
        i += 2;
    }
}
```

Comment: Please define reverse.  Do you mean you want to extrapolate the logic to allow it to be more readable?

Comment: Reverse - as in get back the original input, if given the output from this.

Comment: `&` is a destructive operator. You are losing information when you apply it, and so will never be able to reverse it, in the general case.

Comment: That's what I was afraid of.  The & was a big red flag for me.

Comment: You're going to run into some trouble trying to retrieve the original input.  If the value is `msg[i]` is greater than 15, and/or the value in msg[i+1] is greater than 4095 you will be losing data.  the `&` is a BITWISE AND operator.  You can essentially think of it as a chunking operator that takes only returns 1 for the bits that match up.  So 0x0f is 15 and 0xfff is 4095.  If you know anything about binary, both of those values are on the cusp of the next binary digit meaning they are all ones

Comment: I don't know exactly what the purpose of this manipulation is, but I do know that data comes into this system, it runs through this function at some point, and then after that gets written to long term storage  as so called "raw" data that can "played back" so to speak.  It normally feeds into the program at a higher level, but I want to feed it back in from the very beginning of  the process.

Comment: Note: it looks to me like all the values in msg[] are in the range of 0 to 255.

Comment: Could you give us test data?

Comment: @BuvinJ in that case, half of the data is lost (the most significant four bits, so the new data is `mod(data, 16)`, so the maximum return msg will be 15).

Answer (score 1):

My version, behold:

```
public void undoFunc(int[] newMsg, int[] original) {
        int i = SOME_LENGTH_CONSTANT; // starting point
        for (int j = 0; j < newMsg.length; j++) { // Iterate over newMsg
            
            original[i] = ~((newMsg[j]&0xff00)>>8)&0x000f; // &0x000f to get rid of "mistakes" when NOT-ing
            original[i+1] = (~(newMsg[j]&0x00ff)) & 0xff;
            // i = initial value + 2 * j
            i+=2;
        }
    }
```

**What does your code do?**
The input is an integer array. Every two values are used to create one value in the 'output' (`newMsg`) array.

1. First, it removes the left four bits of the first value in the input.
2. Then it "scrolls" that value 8 places to the left and puts zeroes in the empty spots.
3. It places the second value, `msg[i+1]`, in the zeroes in the four rightmost bits.
4. It negates the value, all ones become zeroes and all zeroes become ones.
5. When 4) was done, the 4 leftmost bits (cleared in step 1)) become ones, so it undoes this with a `&0x0FFF`.

Example iteration:

```
msg[i] ==   1010'1011
msg[i+1] == 0010'0100

1) 1010'1011           ->           0000'1011
2) 0000'1011           -> 0000'1011'0000'0000
3) 0000'1011'0000'0000 -> 0000'1011'0010'0100
4) 0000'1011'0010'0100 -> 1111'0100'1101'1011
5) 1111'0100'1101'1011 -> 0000'0100'1101'1011

newMsg[j] == 0000'0100'1101'1011 == 0x04DB (I think, from memory)
```

**What my code does:**
Getting the value of (what used to be) `msg[i+1]` is easy, it's the opposite/`NOT` of the rightmost 8 bits. Because negating it turns all leading zeroes into ones, I'll `AND` it with `0xff`.
Getting the value of (what used to be) `msg[i]` was more difficult. First scrolled the leftmost 8 bits to the right. Then I negate the value. But the four unused/lost bits are now ones, and I expect that the OP wants these to be zeroes, so I `&0x000f` it.

NOTE: I used hexes with leading zeroes to make it more clear. These are not necessary.
NOTE: I divided the binary numbers into four bits for readability. So `0000'0100'1101'1011` is actually (`0b`)`0000010011011011`.

The values of `msg[i+1]` are recovered, but the leftmost four bits of `msg[i]` are lost.

*Fwew.*

---

#### Original Post:

In your code, you use `&`. What `&` does, is turn all 'agreeing bits' (when a bit from byte `a` and the equally significant bit from byte b are both 1) into `1`s and the rest into `0`s. This means that all bits that don't agree are, as @Mike Harris said, gone and destroyed.

Example `&` (and operation):

```
1010 & 0110 =
    1  &  0 => 0
    0  &  1 => 0
    1  &  1 => 1
    0  &  0 => 0
= 0010
```

As you see, only the second and third most significant bits (or zero-inclusive first and second least significant bit) of byte `a` are kept (bit #4/#0 is 'luck'), because they are `1`s in byte `b`.

You can reverse all bits that are `1`s in byte `b` in your code (one of which is `fff`, or `1111 1111 1111` in binary, though remember all bits more significant than the first one are removed, because `1111 1111 1111 == 000000000...00111111111111`). But this won't reverse it, and only works depending on what the purpose of reversing it is.

[More about the AND Bitwise operation on Wikipedia.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bitwise_operation#AND)

Comment: This function seems to be means of data compression.  The | of two consecutive values here is reducing two ints into one effectively.  I think that the &'s are range control operations.  Values greater than 0x0f, or 0xfff can be reduced to their maximums because ultimately they are evaluated based on thresholds in this program anyway.  At least that's what I'm guessing.  I know that despite the destructive effects of the &s, no required data is being lost.

Comment: In that case, it can be reversed, but the range control will affect it, so `input != reversedFunc(someFunc(input))`.

Comment: Right.  That's what I'm hoping now.  It might not literally be that the reversed input is identical, but it's interpretation by the subsequent parts of the program would be.  I expect to be discarding and faking other chunks of the data set from these raw "play back" files.  I'm trying to emulate core portions of what happens with the data even if I can't get a true replication of what was there originally.

Comment: Done. See my revision. I can recover `msg[i+1]` completely and the four least significant bits from `msg[i]` (given an even i).

Comment: Thanks, Duncan!  I'll give it a shot on Monday when I'm back at work.

Comment: I shelved this temporarily and "cheated" by storing my own test data files with some original data for now.  I upvoted you for the help though.  I may go back and try to use this code, however.

Comment: BTW, I learned that the data flowing into this is coming in "integer pairs".  One unit of data is not coming in to the system in a single int, some of it's bits overflow into another int.  This compression function merges them together and discards the extraneous bits.   (The data originates from a collection of physical sensors that somehow hook into a custom OS...) Point being, this IS non-lossy.  Your function should serve the desired purpose.

Answer (score 1):

I just wanted to try to do it, here is the results of my attempt.

In the beginning I split the expression into single operations:

1. `int t1 = msg[i] & 0x0f;`

   Here is we lose all except for the last 4 bits.
2. `int t2 = t1 << 8;`

   Clear low 8 bits by shifting `t1`.
3. `int t3 = t2 | msg[i + 1];`

   Here we should understand if `m[i + 1]` is large than 255 (particularly `m[i + 1] & 0xf00 > 0`), we are not able to restore the low 4 bits of `m[i]` because they are irreversibly overwritten.
4. `int t4 = ~t3;`

   Just a negation.
5. `newMsg[j] = t4 & 0xfff;`

   Take low 12 bits.

---

Just did these steps in reverse order:

```
public static void someFuncRev(int[] msg, int[] newMsg) {
    for (int i = 0; i < msg.length; ++i) {
        newMsg[2 * i] = (~msg[i] >> 8) & 0xf; // take 11-8 bits
        newMsg[2 * i + 1] = ~msg[i] & 0xff; // take 7-0 bits
    }
}
```

I assumed `SOME_LENGTH_CONSTANT == 0`. It is easy to adjust the constant.

---

So, when the values inside `msg` are <=15, the function above recovers the initial sequence. 
In case when the values are >15 and <=255, for `msg[i]` we can restore only 4 bits, `msg[i + 1]` are restored completely.
If the values are >255, we can't restore `msg[i]` because it was correpted by bits of `msg[i + 1]` (look above at the point no. 3); can restore 8 bits of `msg[i + 1]`.

I hope this helps you.

Comment: Thanks, Enegue!  That is greatly appreciated. I'll give it a shot.  (I may have wait until Monday though, sorry).  The sticking points really are whether this program will work correctly with the data loses.  If we assume it does, your solution looks to be on the right track.  I had something similar, but abandoned it temporarily.  I'm thinking it might be easier for me to just record a pile of unmolested test data, and then feed it back into the system.  I'd love use to the so called "raw files" which already exist and represent real world use, but I can't get hung up too badly on this idea.